# Python ListNode object update in a linked list doesn't work as expected

Tags: python, linked-list

Let's say we're trying to implement a linked list in Python, with each ListNode defined as following:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, val=0, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
```

And let's also say we have a simple linked list of `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> None`, defined as following:

```
a = ListNode(1)
b = ListNode(2)
c = ListNode(3)
a.next = b
b.next = c
```

Now when I hold a variable pointing to `c` and update itself like this:

```
c = c.next
```

I expected that the linked list from `a` will look like: `1 -> 2 -> None` because node `c` is updated. However, to my surprise, the linked list from `a` still keeps its original form: `1 -> 2 -> 3 -> None`.

Why is this the case? Doesn't the variable `c` hold the actual reference to that `ListNode` object and the change to itself should therefore reflect when we see the entire list from node `a`?

Comment: Assignment doesn't do what you're thinking. I recommend reading https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: assignment to a variable never changes a data structure. A variable is a reference to an object. By assigning a different object (reference) to that variable never has an impact on the previous reference that this variable might have held.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignment to a name (variable) never mutates a data structure, like setting an attribute of an object.

Here is your linked list:

```
  a:┐             b:┐             c:┐
    │               │               │
┌───┴───────┐   ┌───┴───────┐   ┌───┴───────┐
│ val: 1    │   │ val: 2    │   │ val: 3    │
│ next: ────────┤ next: ────────┤ next: None│
└───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘
```

Once you assign `c = c.next`, you're taking the value of `c.next` -- which is `None` and assign it to the `c` name:

```
  a:┐             b:┐             c: None
    │               │                
┌───┴───────┐   ┌───┴───────┐   ┌───────────┐
│ val: 1    │   │ val: 2    │   │ val: 3    │
│ next: ────────┤ next: ────────┤ next: None│
└───────────┘   └───────────┘   └───────────┘
```

When you'd want that `b.next` becomes `None`, you'll really have to assign that to `b.next`. Note that `b.next` is an attribute that is *distinct* from the name `c`.